# Why would IdentityServer4 demo application's implicit client flow send me back an access_token that is the same as the id_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using a variant of the in-memory clients defined in [the reference `IdentityServer4` demo project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo) and after I log into the Identity Server and get redirected, the URI is such that the `id_token` and `access_token` are the same exact JWT.

Is this a sensible behavior? Why would you want the `id_token` and `access_token` to be the same, ever? Maybe if you don't care about the `access_token`?

Comment: are they exactly the same? because they look very similar at the start usually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean same exact JWT. But both access token and ID token can come as JWT tokens.

One good example is OAuth flow of Azure AD. According to the document successful token response return an access token and an id token (yes, Azure does send one for OAuth auth. code flow) both in JWT format ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1)). But their contents could be different. For example, one could be a signed JWT and other could not be.

Reason for the usage of JWT is due to self-contained nature of them. For example, token validations can be done easily from client application end as well as protected API end.

Usually if both access token and ID token are JWTs they could be differ by claims. For example audience claim (`"aud"`) could be different depending on intended audience of token.